# How do I read my program to a flat file in C++?

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2015

I'm building a small Physics engine in C++ that launches a projectile on a set of launch parameters by the user (height, angle, time interval and initial velocity), then displays some information such as the total distance or angle at every time interval that it's in the air until it hits the ground. Just so you can see, here's my program:

```
cout << "Insert a lanuch Angle (theta): ";  
cin >> thetaDegrees;    
cout << "Insert a launch height: ";     
cin >> yOld;            
cout << "Insert an initial velocity: ";     
cin >> initialVelocity;     
cout << "Time (DeltaT) in seconds: ";   
cin >> totalT;

for (double deltaTime = 0.0; deltaTime < totalT; deltaTime += 0.1) {

const double squared = deltaTime * deltaTime;       // squared constant for deltaTime squared

theta = thetaDegrees * PI / 180;    // converts theta to a degrees value

velocityX = initialVelocity * cos(theta);   // calculates Vx
velocityY = initialVelocity * sin(theta);   // calculates Vy

// apply initialV to velocity
velocity = initialVelocity + 9.8 * time;

xNew = xOld + velocity * time;  // works out displacement for X

yNew = yOld + velocity * deltaTime - gravitiyHalf / 0.5 * (squared);    // calculates Y

velocityY = velocity - 9.8 * deltaTime; // includes gravity to Y

angle = atan2(yNew, xNew) * 180 / PI;   // convert angle to degrees

cout << "\nHeight: " << yNew << endl;
cout << "Distance in Meters: " << xNew << "m" << endl;
cout << "Angle: " << angle << endl;
cout << "Time: " << deltaTime << "s " << endl;

if (heightCheck == false) {
    maxHeight = yOld;
    // keep maxheight equal to previous height
}

if (yNew < yOld && heightCheck == false) {
    heightCheck = true;
    // if projectile is going down, trigger maxheight
}

cout << "Maximum height:  " << maxHeight << endl;

if ((yNew < 0) || (deltaTime == totalT)) {
    getchar();      // stops if delta t = total T or projectile landed
}

yOld = yNew;    // refresh x & y
xOld = xNew;
}
```

In my coursework brief, I'm told the following:

> The   software    must    be  able    to  output  two flat    files   so  your    work    can be  checked

So **I need to be able to output my program to a file**, what does this mean and how do I do this?

Comment: You need to be able to write position and velocity vectors as a function of time to files.  Do you know how to open a file and write to it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at the [fstream](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/fstream/fstream/) library, which is the C++ standard way of performing file input and output. More specifically, look at creating a file `std::fstream out( "output.txt", std::fstream::out )`, and writing to the file `std::string word = "some text"; out << word;`.

Using fstream, you can write any basic type to a file, so you can write plain numbers (fixed or floating point) using `out << number`, and it all works effectively the same as `std::cout`.